# How to use jQuery Grep to filter extremely nested JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm too new at JS to know how to write a `return` properly. Basically `lenders` is an array of people, each of whom have items, each of which has requests, each of which has a start and end date. When the user punches in a start/end date to search, I need to look through the JSON object, and IF any item has a request that has a start/end date that overlaps with what the user has searched for, then that item needs to be excluded from the results.

Original `lenders` JSON

```
[
  {"email":"test@yahoo.com","inventories":
    [
      {"name":"2-Person Tent","requests":
        [
          {"pickupdate":"2015-01-03","returndate":"2015-01-08"},
          {"pickupdate":"2015-02-01","returndate":"2015-02-02"}
        ]
      },
      {"name":"Sleeping bag","requests":
        [
          {"pickupdate":"2015-02-01","returndate":"2015-02-02"}
        ]
      },
      {"name":"Sleeping bag","requests":[]},
    ]
  },
  {"email":"test@gmail.com",,"inventories":[]}
] 
...
```

If the `user` searches for `pickupdate 2015-01-03` until `returndate 2015-01-07` for example, that overlaps with a request for a 2-person tent, and so the result of the `grep` function should be:

New `lenders` JSON

```
[
  {"email":"test@yahoo.com","inventories":
    [
      // 2-Person tent has been removed by grep function
      {"name":"Sleeping bag","requests":
        [
          {"pickupdate":"2015-02-01","returndate":"2015-02-02"}
        ]
      },
      {"name":"Sleeping bag","requests":[]},
    ]
  },
  {"email":"test@gmail.com",,"inventories":[]}
] 
...
```

I have a great starting point from @Олег Ильин that helped me figure out how to drill down into the `Request` objects, but the `is_valid` part is not working, the returned array of inventories the exact same before and after the `grep` function. Additional help?

```
  function FilterLenders() { 
    console.log(lenders[0].inventories)
    for(var n=0; n<lenders.length; n++){
      inventories = lenders[n].inventories
      inventories = jQuery.grep(inventories, function (inventory) {
        var is_valid;
        requests = inventory.requests;
        for(var x=0; x<requests.length; x++){
          var pickupdate_request = moment(requests[x].pickupdate)
          var returndate_request = moment(requests[x].returndate)
          var test = (pickupdate_request - returndate_search) * (pickupdate_search - returndate_request)
          if(test > 0) {
            //dates completely overlap the item that had this request needs to be excluded
            is_valid = false;
          } else if(test === 0) {
            //dates are on the edge of each other, for now the item that had this request can be included
            is_valid = true;
          } else if(test <0) {
            //dates do not overlap at all, item should definitely be included
            is_valid = true
          }
        }
      })
    }
    console.log(lenders[0].inventories) //first object, 2-person tent, should not exist
  }
```

Also, had another idea to do this, but the problem is that here, it never `returns false`, even though if I put a `console.log("false")`, that would show me a `false` exists

```
function FilterLenders() { 
  console.log(lenders[1].inventories)
  for(var n=0; n<lenders.length; n++){
    inventories = lenders[n].inventories
    inventories = jQuery.grep(inventories, function (inventory) {
      function check(inventory) {
        requests = inventory.requests;
        for(var x=0; x<requests.length; x++){
          var pickupdate_request = moment(requests[x].pickupdate)
          var returndate_request = moment(requests[x].returndate)
          var test = (pickupdate_request - returndate_search) * (pickupdate_search - returndate_request)
          if(test > 0) {
            //dates completely overlap the item that had this request needs to be excluded
            return false;
            //altho return doesn't seem to work, if I put a console.log("false") here it will correctly log a false entry...
            break;
          } else if(test === 0) {
            //dates are on the edge of each other, for now the item that had this request can be included
            return true;
          } else if(test <0) {
            //dates do not overlap at all, item should definitely be included
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      console.log(check(inventory))
      if( check(inventory) ) {
        return inventory
      }
    })
  }
  console.log(lenders[1].inventories) //object 5 should not exist
}
```

Comment: `starting_db` looks like an object(key value pair) not like an array

Comment: @ArunPJohny you're right, I left out a ton of detail yesterday. Anyways, I fixed the question, can you help?

Comment: @james how does the date comparison work in the above example?

Comment: @SalmanA Basically you take two dates, and you subtract the beginnings and ends to get `var test` and then per mathematical rules, if you get a positive number, the dates are overlapping, negative the dates are not, and if you get 0, then one of the dates are overlapping right at the edge (e.g., pickup at 9th, return on 9th)

Answer (score 1):

If jquery.grep solution is too complex you can use specialized filters as [json easy filter](https://www.npmjs.org/package/json-easy-filter)
See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MSppcoAziqsQpTDGpLA1?p=info)

```
var start = new Date('2015-01-03');
var end = new Date('2015-01-07');
var success = new Jef(data).remove(function (node) {
    if (node.has('requests')) {
        var requests = node.value.requests;
        for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
            var request = requests[i];
            var pick = new Date(request.pickupdate);
            var ret = new Date(request.returndate);
            if (!((pick < start && ret < start) || (pick > end && ret > end))) {
                // pickupdate-returndate overlaps with start-end
                return node;
            }
        }
    }
});

alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Function:

```
function moment(date){
    var y = date.substring(0,4),
        m = date.substring(5,7),
        d = date.substring(8,10),
        newdate = new Date(y, m, d);

    return newdate.getTime();
}

pickupdate_search = '2015-01-03';
returndate_search = '2015-01-07';

function FilterLenders() {
console.log(lenders[0]);

for (var n = 0; n < lenders.length; n++) {
    inventories = lenders[n].inventories;
    lenders[n].inventories = jQuery.grep(inventories, function(inventory) {
            var is_valid,
                x = 0,
                requests = inventory.requests,
                l = requests.length;

            for (; x < l; x++) {
                var pickupdate_request = moment(requests[x].pickupdate),
                    returndate_request = moment(requests[x].returndate),
                    return_search = moment(returndate_search),
                    pickup_search = moment(pickupdate_search);

                    if((pickup_search >= pickupdate_request) && (return_search <= returndate_request)){
                        //dates completely overlap the item that had this request needs to be excluded
                        is_valid = false;
                        console.log('false');
                        break;
                    }else{
                        console.log('true');
                        is_valid  = true;
                    }
            }
            return is_valid;
        }); 
    }
    console.log(lenders[0]); //first object, 2-person tent, should not exist
}
FilterLenders();
```

Comment: thanks but I can't get the `is_valid` to work. I also realized I left a lot of pieces out of the question yesterday so I revised the question to be more comprehensive and adapted your code. Can you help me take a second look?

Comment: sorry still not working for me. It looks like the key difference is that you added a `break` for the `is_valid false`?

Comment: i've also added another idea that I was thinking about to the question